# gitlab add project to existing milestone

Tags: gitlab, milestone

I want to use gitlab group milestones.

When adding a new milestone, it is possible to add several projects.
When creation is finished and saved, there is no way to add a project afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a milestone with exactly the same name and due date
and it got automatically assigned to the correct group milestone.
They even don't have the same ids in their respective repositories.
So it seems like they just need to be equal and not the same…

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Works perfectly for me.